# Hosting a multithreaded .NET core server app in GCP flexible environment?

Tags: google-app-engine, .net-core, google-cloud-platform, app-engine-flexible

I need to create a service in .NET Core that will watch a queue and periodically create multiple threads for processing. There is no Web API component, no front end, just processing and it needs to be hosted in GCP.

I know I could leverage Google Compute for that purpose and that it would be the natural choice but is there any particular reason I shouldn't or couldn't host the application in the GCP Flexible Environment? Are there any limitations or pricing consequences that make it a bad idea?

Comment: App Engine Flexible is a very good choice. Plus the deployment tools make deployments and updates a breeze. Just think containers and you have App Engine Flexible.

Comment: The available documentation suggest that AppEngine is not really intended for long running background processes. I get that it’s a container, but is there any reason I shouldn’t use that for a non-web app?

Comment: Wade - I might not have thought my comment thru completely. Yes, there are issues with accessing Flexible when using URLs as they have a time limit. That limit can be changed. I use Flexible for running jobs such as Apache Beam (Dataflow) with no problems except for autoscaling (which does not work well with CPU bound tasks). For your case I would stick with GCE or Containers on GCE. BTW: Do you have the link for your comment? I would like to review Google's position.